# Determine the gender to use with the "all" pronoun

Tags: pronoun

I have encountered the following sentence: "Sie kämpfen mit allem, was sie haben". Similarly "Ich habe alles verloren."

It is clear to me that **mit** requires **Dativ** in the first one and that the second one is **Akkusativ**, but how do I tell the gender?

Why not aller instead of allem in the first sentence? Why neutral in the second?

Comment: Where do you see a gender?

Comment: I believe @Hallowed is talking about different conjugations, see for example [here](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/adjektive/deklination). The wiktionary entry for *all* gives *allem* as the `Dativ Singular Maskulinum` and `Neutrum`; and *aller* as the `Dativ Singular Femininum`.

Comment: @blutorange: yup, you are right, the word conjugations just didn't spring in my mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are obviously confusing two different variations of the word:

- *alle* = all of "them", all of a previously mentioned or implied group, usually persons
  genitive: aller, dative: allen, accusative: alle
- *alles* = generally "everything".
  genitive: alles, dative: allem, accusative: alles

> Sie kämpfen mit allem, was sie haben.
>   *They are fighting by all available means.*
>
> Sie kämpfen mit allen, die sie haben.
>   *They are fighting with all the men they have.*
>
> Ich habe alles verloren.
>   *I have lost everything (e.g. my house, my family, my job, …).*
>
> Ich habe alle verloren.
>   *I have lost everybody [I loved/I had etc.]*

If there is some context around the sentence, the word *alle* can also refer to things:

> Ich hatte fünf **Ringe**, aber habe **alle** verloren.
>   *I once had five rings, but have lost all of them.*
>
> Sie haben viele **Waffen**. Sie kämpfen mit **allen**, die sie haben.
>   *They have lots of weapons. They are fighting with all [weapons] they have.*

Comment: From a practical point of view I agree, but dictionaries list „alles“ as a form of „all“.

Comment: Du könntest noch auf die Frage des Geschlechts eingehen.